# Copying an existing EBS backed AMI to include in auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, autoscaling

In my auto scaling group I want to copy my existing AMI and copy it to bring up a new instance.

I can easily use a script to create the new instance but the developers change the code without committing to git hub so the new instance will not have the changes.So bootstrap or user script is out of the windows.

Creating a snapshot and making an instance manually is been ruled out.

I there any way using AWS CLI or SDK so that I can copy an existing running AMI and bring it up in auto scaling group.

Comment: Have you considered using AWS CodeDeploy? That would trigger deployments of code to your servers from the github repos? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html

Comment: As i have told earlier only the code in the running AMI is not up to date there are differences between code there and git ,thankx to uncontrolled dev fixes in  the production ...so i am left with option to only make a snapshot of the running AMI, i want to do it programatically...or is there any better option

Comment: It seems like the "better option" is not to make changes on the live server, or at least, commit them to the repo and launch from the repo.